# Jaspersoft studio query depending parameter

Tags: parameters, jasper-reports

I'm trying to create parameter which depends on another parameter and second query.
Second query should be something like this:

```
select first_name from user
where id = $P{ID_param}
```

ID_param is inserted by user and then this second parameter should be calculated with that query and it is just one value, not a list.
Then, second parameter is used to calculate main query.

Jaspersoft studio doesn't support second query in report (like singlevaluequery in Pentaho) so I have to use Input control. Looks like that there is no option for creating Input control in my case.
I have tried with single-select query type, and in report I tried String and Collection type of parameter, but every time I get same error

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0.

I also tried with single-value but in that case I can not use query.

Any ideas how to create query depending parameter which return only single value (not a list) or how to create Input control which will use query that return single value (not a list)?

Comment: using subdataset or subreport you can execute a second query that depends on result of first query

Comment: `Jaspersoft studio doesn't support second query in report(like singlevaluequery in Pentaho) so I have to use Input control. ` - What to do you mean?

Comment: Subdata set work with charts, crosstabs, tables and lists only. My main query depends on parameter which I have to calculate first. So, user enter first param, then I need to calculate second parameter somehow and then main query which depends on second parameter.